# SSIS collection pulling two versions of the same database into single destination for consolidation - missing columns from one source

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm working on an SSIS collection where I am pulling tables over from two source systems into a consolidated database on a third server. The company is split into two entities, and entity A is on the most up to date version of our sales system. Entity B is a version behind and therefore is missing some of the columns that we have in entity A.

I have the collection setup into a for each loop container as to dynamically pass in connection strings and other items for logging, etc. The problem I'm running into is the column mismatch between the two source systems. Is there a way for me to have the SSIS package hit all of the same tables in a loop for each of the two source servers and not fail on or ignore the columns that exist for entity A, but not entity B? I'm really trying to avoid making this into two SSIS packages if possible.

Comment: Instead of importing a table, you could import from a SQL statement.  And build the statement dynamically based on the source system.  Add the missing columns as NULL or N/A values in your query.

Comment: This migration issue is a common one and will be a pain no matter what to do by hand in ssis.  I would look into installing bimlexpress and generating one set of packages for each source in biml.  Here is a tutorial you can check out: https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/CopyDataDynamicallywithBimlScript/

Comment: @Wouter how would you suggest implementing that? I have the queries for each source system as variables right now and I have my DFTs in a ForEach Loop. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to tell my DFT to pull variableQueryA if source is sourceA and variableQueryB if the source is sourceB.